# build.ninja generate took too long time on 8G ram machine

Tags: android, ninja, blueprint, android-soong

Building machine info(Non building status):

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       314Mi       7.2Gi       0.0Ki       181Mi       7.2Gi
Swap:          17Gi       1.4Gi        16Gi
```

The building logs,

```
[100% 1/1] out/soong/.minibootstrap/minibp out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
[ 98% 80/81] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
     2188:18 out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
```

So, the file "out/soong/build.ninja" generate took too long time.
Whether can optimizing the time? I check the source code of build/blueprint, but no ideas.

Comment: Your RAM is usually irrelevant. Did you `ninja -j <insert your core count without brackets here>` when running Ninja?

Comment: No, Ninja depend on build.ninja. so need to generate build.ninja file firstly.

Comment: `-j coreCount` still works on most build systems, and it kinda has to use a build system to bootstrap ninja in the first place. Either way, your CPU is the bottleneck, not your RAM

Comment: Do you know how to using Ninja build directly on Android? as I know, it need blueprint for generate to build.ninja, so next I can use Ninja tools.